# laravel errors in live server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I see many questions are same with my question.
i was check all answer.But didn't solved my problem.
My site : https://butterhalf.net/ 
here i see :-

```
View [welcome] not found.
```

After some seconds :-

```
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\project\laravel\storage\framework/sessions/8OAQROGAWLuJePfyeY3K2O2V06l3Pe85ttVcXDme): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

i didn't understand why i see `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\laravel\` . i was clear cache & views data before uploading.

Comment: The welcome view is working. I am able to see 'butterhalf.net' which is the welcome view, right?

Comment: its fresh laravel

Comment: not my site here now